# Removing the "Show All" category from the portfolio gallery with filtering category

Tags: java, html, css

I'm currently working on a portfolio gallery in one template.

I have Portfolio Gallery with filtering category
I want to remove the whole category "Show All" and set another one first.
I tried this code but it only removes the button.

```
.button-group .button[data-filter="*"] {
display: none;
```

}

How can I do this?

I appreciate the answers

[portfolio gallery](https://codepen.io/ValentinaY/project/editor/DvWkvy#)

Answer (score 0):

I make it.

1.Rename

```
<a class="button is-checked" data-filter="*"><span>Show all</span></a>
```

with

```
<a class="button is-checked" data-filter=".klinkers"><span>KLINKERS</span></a>
```

2.I add filter in

```
/* Filter - Isotope */
var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: '.klinkers'
});
```

---> filter: '.klinkers'